# Adding additional content to an array

Tags: arrays

I have this array which is perfect, but i need to add some additional content to it, but i'm extremely uncertain about how to approach this addon.

Here is my working code:

```
\[
  \begin{array}{c| *{4}{C{2em}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{>} & =\joinrel+ & =\joinrel- & \multicolumn{1}{c}{<} \\
    \hline
    > & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    =\joinrel+ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    =\joinrel- & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    < & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}
\]
```

And the result:

[image]

I would like to add following to this array based on this example (does not have to be exactly this example, but something close enough):

[image]

Comment: You could make an array of subarrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: array]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\usepackage{graphicx}% for \rotatebox

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempwidth}
\newlength{\tempheight}

\begin{document}
%calculate size of left brace and overbrace
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\begin{array}{@{}C{2em}C{2em}C{2em}C{2em}@{}}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}$}
\settoheight{\tempheight}{\usebox{\tempbox}}
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\[
  \begin{array}{cc|c}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \textrm{text}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \overbrace{\rule{\tempwidth}{0pt}} \\
    && \begin{array}{@{}C{2em}C{2em}C{2em}C{2em}@{}} > & =\joinrel+ & =\joinrel- & < \end{array} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{text}\left\lbrace\rule{0pt}{\tempheight}\right. &
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} > \\ =\joinrel+ \\ =\joinrel- \\ < \end{array} &
    \usebox{\tempbox}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

One could also use \resizebox and \rotatebox to create the large braces.

Comment: Spot on! Works exactly as intended :-)

Comment: One last thing, how do i make the vertical and horizontal line in the array thick? I dont see any `|` in the declaration..

Comment: It's there, in the first array after the start of the equation.